# hasnext() in iterator is not working as expected

Tags: java, iterator, json

I have difficulty in using `hasNext()` iterator method. I have a `JSONArray`:

```
JSONArray = [{"a":1},{"b":2,"c":3}]
```

I am accessing one `JSONObject` at a time. First `JSONObject` in the `JSONarray` has one element second have two elements. The issue is that when the iterator check `hasNext()` on first `JSONObject` with one element it gives true, my understanding is that it should give true only if it has more elements then the present one. Please help and clarify this.

```
for (int i=0; i<JArrayLength; i++) {

            JSONObject obj = newJArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Iterator k = obj.keys();
            System.out.println("Value k.hasnext is = " + k.hasNext());
            if(k.hasNext())
            { //print somehting} // here its printing but as the value should be false it should not for i=0.
}
```

Please suggest where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the iterator

```
Iterator k = obj.keys();
```

and then immediately check to see whether it has keys. Since you haven't consumed the first key (`a`), of course it does.

Note also that you're getting warnings about using the raw type `Iterator`. Pay attention to them and parameterize appropriately (probably with `<String>`).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am not able to get it. How should I be consuming the first key then. The value of k in this should be the no. of keys in json object or their values, i tried printing k to check but it gives -Value k is = java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator@4e9722c9

Comment: No, the *value* of `k` is an `Iterator`. The number of items in the underlying data structure isn't visible, as it may be indeterminate (iterating over a network stream) or infinite (a generator).

Answer (score 0):

hasNext checks the iterator if it has any values to iterate to actually get the value you should do:

```
if(k.hasNext()){
      k.next(); // gets the actual value
}
```

> hasNext() Returns true if the iteration has more elements.
>
> next() Returns the next element in the iteration.

Comment: Thanks for replying but this is not my doubt, its answered above tx anyway :)